# Understanding reduce() behavior

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble understanding how reduce() works in the following situation. Greatly appreciate your help!

```js
let order = [
  {amount: 1},
  {amount: 2},
  {amount: 3},
  {amount: 4}
];

//This returns the correct result: 10 
let total1 = order.reduce((sum, a) => sum + a.amount, 0);

//This returns NaN. Why?
let total2 = order.reduce((a, b) => a.amount + b.amount);
```

Comment: While `b.amount` is the element's amount (eg, 1,2,3,4) `a.amount` is not the same thing. It is `1.amount`, `2.amount` etc. Since numbers don't have an `amount` property you will get `1.amount == undefined`

Comment: Reduce is: `Array.prototype.reduce((accumulator, element_in_array) => {}, initial_value_of_accumulator)`

Comment: Because you never should use `reduce` without an initial value, the result of your callback function must have the same type as its first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let order = [
  {amount: 1},
  {amount: 2},
  {amount: 3},
  {amount: 4}
];

//This returns the correct result: 10 
let total1 = order.reduce((sum, a) => sum + a.amount, 0);

//If we switch a.amount to a then we get the right answer
let total2 = order.reduce((a, b) => a + b.amount, 0);

console.log(total2);
```

How reduce works is it has an accumulator (first input) and the cur value (second input).
Then you can edit the accumulator as it goes through the array.

If we want to find the sum then we add the amount of the cur value (`b.amount`) to the accumulator (`a`)